# PDO beginTransaction in two separate scripts

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

What happens when two different clients call the same php function that have pdo::beginTransaction?

Does one of them fail or can two instances of php execute the contents of a beginTranscation commit block?

IE:

```
try{
db::beginTransaction();
//queries here
//can two separate php instances go in here at the same time?
db:commit();
}
catch(error e)
{
 db::rollback();
}
```

Comment: That depends on the database you're using, but generally transactions are handled per connection and all modern databases support multiple connections with transactions in each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each instance of a PHP script (more accurately, each instance of PDO) opens up a connection to the database (from the DB perspective, a new session). Backend databases (with the exception of a few flat-file ones) support multiple connections, but end up locking their individual resources differently. Depending on the queries executed in your transaction, you may end up causing a deadlock. That said, having multiple connections to the database open at the same time does not necessarily put you in a deadlock scenario.

Comment: But if both of the files are being included on one page with includes then it is not multiple scripts so you should only have one database connection that you can pass around right?

Comment: Depends on whether or not you're using the same PDO instance. While you can have multiple connections to the same DB during the life of a PHP script, it's not recommended unless you have a specific reason for doing so. Best practice would be to use a single connection per PHP request.

Comment: I only use one PDO object per script and only make a connection at the beginning of the script and terminate it at the end.